# Calling a method inside another method JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, this

I am currently learning OOP in JavaScript. I'm refactoring an app and I have a problem.

I have created a Class "Weather"

```
 class Weather {

  constructor({longitude, latitude} = {}) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
  }

  getLongitude(){
    return this.longitude;
  }

  setLongitude(longitude){
    this.longitude = longitude;
  }

  getLatitude(){
    return this.latitude;
  }

  setLatitude(latitude){
    this.latitude = latitude;
  }

  getLocation() {
      if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
          //if locatin is enabled, show position in button
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success, this.fail, this.options);
      } else {
          alert("Sorry, you browser doesn't have geolocation");
      }
  }

   success(position){
    let pos = position.coords;
    console.log('Your actual position is :');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${pos.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${pos.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${position.coords.accuracy} meters.`);
    this.setLongitude(pos.longitude); // <== Doesn't work
    this.setLatitude(pos.latitude); // <== Doesn't work

  }

  fail(){
    console.log('User refused to give position');
  }
}
```

Everything works, I can retrieve longitude and latitude like that

```
let City = new Weather();
City.getLocation(); //will call getLocation and on success, it will console.log the longitude and latitude
```

My problem is that I can update the value of my object. When I create my object, the constuctor defines a longitude and latitude if they are passed as argument. However, in the success method, I cannot reassign value of the object.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: You may find its to do with the scope of the `this` variable, common practice is to put a `var self = this;` at the top, and use self where you want the class this reference.

Comment: You can use setters and getters of class javascript

Comment: You may also do like `success(position){bla bla}.bind(this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've lost the context because the `success` method is passed as a reference. So the value of `this` when it is called does not refer to the `Weather` instance. You can use `Function.prototype.bind` method to fix this:

```
class Weather {
  ...

  getLocation() {
    if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
      //if locatin is enabled, show position in button
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        this.success.bind(this),
        this.fail,
        this.options
      );
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, you browser doesn't have geolocation");
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can bind the method in the constructor, so that `bind` is only called once when the object is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Walks say you are having troubles with the "this" value inside succes s function

Ther are several ways to solve it, the problem is when navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition calls success, it sets a different "this" value that you expect on the function

One could be

```
var me = this;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    me.success(position)
}, this.fail, this.options)
```

You will have the same proble with this.fail

Another way is

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.success.bind(this), this.fail.bind(this), this.options)
```

You can learn more from here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Edited: As sugested first solution is wrong, a pointer to this is need

Comment: In that first example you'd still lose the `this` unless you use a `var me = this;`. You could use an arrow function for the wrapper instead to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getters and setters of class javascript.

```
class Weather {
   constructor({longitude, latitude} = {}) { 
     this.longitude = longitude;
     this.latitude = latitude;
     ...
   }

   get Latitude(){return this.latitude};
   set Latitude(args){this.latitude=args};
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: Whilst it is still possible to mimic OOP in JavaScript, you should avoid this approach and instead opt for [Functional Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk&list=PL0zVEGEvSaeEd9hlmCXrk5yUyqUag-n84).

To answer your question:  When you are invoking `success()`, as it happens on every function in JS, the context changes and  `this` will be referring to wherever you invoke the code.

To solve this issue you can either use `bind(this)` or change `success` to a method instead of a function. Here is how it can be done:

```
successs: function(position){
    let pos = position.coords;
    console.log('Your actual position is :');
    console.log(`Latitude : ${pos.latitude}`);
    console.log(`Longitude: ${pos.longitude}`);
    console.log(`More or less ${position.coords.accuracy} meters.`);
    this.setLongitude(pos.longitude); // This will work now because this
    this.setLatitude(pos.latitude); // will be referring to the Weather object
}
```

For further information on how `this` works in JS please have a look at this explanation: http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/